# Ошибка #15 Access denied при использовании метода groups.getRequests VK Api

Tags: vkontakte-api

Получаю токен через Implicit Flow

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&scope=327680&response_type=token
```

Приложение Standalone.

Пытаюсь выполнить запрос groups.getRequests

```
https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getRequests?group_id={groupId}&access_token={accessToken}
```

Получаю ответ

```
{"error":{"error_code":15,"error_msg":"Access denied: no access to call this method","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"groups.getRequests"},{"key":"group_id","value":"xxx"}]}}
```

Через форму внизу страницы https://vk.com/dev/groups.getRequests запрос успешно выполняется на той же группе.

Другие запросы groups.* (кроме groups.approveRequest, с ним такая же ситуация) выполняются без проблем. Что я делаю не так?

Заметил, если токен получить способом Authorization code flow, то метод работает без ошибок. Хотя в документации сказано (https://vk.com/dev/groups.getRequests) что подойдёт токен полученный через Implicit Flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для доступа к некоторым методам, при получении access_token, в параметре redirect_uri нужно указывать значение https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html. Только с такими access_token можно вызывать метод groups.getRequests.